# Linear regression - reduce degrees of freedom

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, pandas, curve-fitting

I have a Pandas dataframe with columns like

```
Order     Balance     Profit cum (%)
```

I'm doing a linear regression

```
model_profit_tr = pd.ols(y=df_closed['Profit cum (%)'], x=df_closed['Order'])
```

The problem with this is that standard model is like (equation of a line that does not pass through the origin)

```
y = a * x + b
```

There is 2 degrees of freedom (a and b)

slope (a):

```
a=model_profit_tr.beta['x']
```

and intercept (b):

```
b=model_profit_tr.beta['intercept']
```

I'd like to reduce degree of freedom for my model (from 2 to 1) and I 'd like to have a model like

```
y = a * x
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `intercept` keyword argument:

```
model_profit_tr = pd.ols(y=df_closed['Profit cum (%)'], 
                         x=df_closed['Order'], 
                         intercept=False)
```

From docs:

```
In [65]: help(pandas.ols) 
Help on function ols in module pandas.stats.interface:

ols(**kwargs)

    [snip]

    Parameters
    ----------
    y: Series or DataFrame
        See above for types
    x: Series, DataFrame, dict of Series, dict of DataFrame, Panel
    weights : Series or ndarray
        The weights are presumed to be (proportional to) the inverse of the
        variance of the observations.  That is, if the variables are to be
        transformed by 1/sqrt(W) you must supply weights = 1/W
    intercept: bool
        True if you want an intercept.  Defaults to True.
    nw_lags: None or int
        Number of Newey-West lags.  Defaults to None.

    [snip]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (for both the solution, and for help tips)!

Comment: I've just an other question but I don't know if I can ask it here... what should I do if I want to set intercept to a given value (other than 0). (I will also reduce the number of degrees of freedom from 2 to 1)

Comment: @FemtoTrader: I don't think `ols` has that functionality. But, considering it does least squares, you can subtract that intercept from `y`, then use `ols` with `intercept=False`. It should be same.

Comment: No that's not the same ! slope is different if you force the line to pass through a given point

Comment: @FemtoTrader: No, in least squares, fitting `a*x + B` to `y` with _fixed_ `B` is same as fitting `a*x` to `y-B`.

Comment: here is a sample to show you that slope is different with fixed B... (so substracting y with fixed B is not the solution) http://pastebin.com/cKUAfeZV

Comment: @FemtoTrader: I don't know what that shows. Of course, the slope is different. They are _different_ models. In your opinion, what slope the _fixed intercept_ one should have?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample showing solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

data = [
(0.2, 1.3),
(1.3, 3.9),
(2.1, 4.8),
(2.9,5.5),
(3.3,6.9)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X', 'Y'])

print(df)

# 2 degrees of freedom : slope / intercept
model_with_intercept = pd.ols(y=df['Y'], x=df['X'], intercept=True)
df['Y_fit_with_intercept'] = model_with_intercept.y_fitted

# 1 degree of freedom : slope ; intersept=0
model_no_intercept = pd.ols(y=df['Y'], x=df['X'], intercept=False)
df['Y_fit_no_intercept'] = model_no_intercept.y_fitted

# 1 degree of freedom : slope ; intersept=offset
offset = -1
df['Yoffset'] = df['Y'] - offset
model_with_offset = pd.ols(y=df['Yoffset'], x=df['X'], intercept=False)
df['Y_fit_offset'] = model_with_offset.y_fitted + offset

print(model_with_intercept)
print(model_no_intercept)
print(model_with_offset)

df.plot(x='X', y=['Y', 'Y_fit_with_intercept', 'Y_fit_no_intercept', 'Y_fit_offset'])
plt.show()
```